# Adding more li elements with 2variables

Tags: javascript, html

Hey i want to do something like to-do list. But with counter.

So when user input a title and date then there will be new element with time counter and title.

For now i got something like this:

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/678z5pgy/1/`
```

But it only changes the "add-new" item h2 and p. I want to append new child for container as li element.

But when i make it as appendchild it will add me new element every second.

(Please don't make it for me just tell me what can i do and where i can look for answer, maybe for loop?)

https://codepen.io/ludzik/pen/YMzKKP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach with setInterval was right but what you do in that Interval is too much. The interval should refresh the displayed remaining time, not the title of your counter.

By accessing elements with `document.getElementById("exampleID")` you will receive this one unique element, which exists only once in your document because an id is unique in a document. It is NOT possible to give two elements the same id. Here is a closer look at the [id attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/hTml/html_id.asp).

It seems you want to add new counters every time you hit the button. So you have to create new elements every time in which you store your data.

- a new `<li>` element (the parent element of the title and time)
- a new `<h2>` element (title)
- a new `<p>` element (time)

In the next step you have to append the `<h2>` and the `<p>` elements to your `<li>` element in the correct order. You do it like this:

```
let headElem = document.createElement("h2")
let timeElem = document.createElement("p")

liElem.appendChild(headElem)
liElem.appendChild(timeElem)
```

This creates to new elements and appends them to the `liElem` element.

Now you can simply append the title of your counter to the title element by assigning it the title to its innerHtml property.

As I said before the only purpose of the interval is to refresh the time. You are saving correctly the values of days, hours and minutes... 
Now you just have to put them in a string like you already did and assign them to the `innerHtml` property of the `timeElem` element.

You can even do this several times a second, since you are calculating the distance from now to the entered date. But that's not the point.

After you set up your interval you just have to append the `liElem` to the `ul` element as described above.

---

If you get stuck: Here is [my version of your script](https://jsfiddle.net/e3ywd5zm/1/).

Here is even a tutorial on [how to create a countdown](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp).

Comment: Thanks man! Right now i understand what i did wrong. 
And my code work. Thank you once again :)